# Manager Accounting signup issue

Tags: 12.10

I installed an accounting software [Manager](http://www.manager.io) in Ubuntu 12.10 and in signup, it is giving the below error. How to get rid of this?

> ATAL ERROR: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was
>   thrown by the type initializer for ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonWriter`1
>   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonWriter --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. File
>   name: 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'   at
>   ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonWriter..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename
>   unknown>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---   at
>   ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString[<>f__AnonymousType8`3]
>   (.<>f_*AnonymousType8`3 value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   ServiceStack.Text.StringExtensions.ToJson[<>f__AnonymousType8`3]
>   (.<>f*_AnonymousType8`3 obj) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Manager.WebServices.Register (System.String name, System.String email,
>   System.String password) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Manager.HttpHandlers.Register.Post () [0x00000] in :0    at HttpFramework.HttpModule.ProcessRequest
>   (HttpFramework.HttpRequest request) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at Manager.HttpModule.ProcessRequest (HttpFramework.HttpRequest
>   request) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is some missing dependency in version published on Ubuntu Software Center. Try to download the latest version directly from the [homepage](http://www.manager.io/download).

Comment: Downloading latest version solved the problem. Thanks